# Can you update a row with the highest ID in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to update a row with the highest ID.
The problem is: I can't find any elegant solution to do this.
This is my best attempt so far:

```
$highestId = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT MAX(id) FROM stats'),0);

mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET views = views +1 WHERE id = $highestId");
```

Maybe there there is a better approach than I am thinking of.

- I am tracking the amount of views, every day
- I want it to auto-increment the last (highest id) day
- In the evening I'm running a cronjob that creates a new day.

Any suggestion on how to tackle this problem are welcome, even if it is a whole different approach.

Table `stats => id | views`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
UPDATE stats SET views = views +1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Question: And what about working with DATE columns? Or is this more efficient? I want it to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: I would say go with the solution that best suits your goal, the difference in fetching a date or a int value wont make any noticable difference. Specially when its just 1 query a day. :)

Comment: The above query will be run about 10 000 times a day. (also not that much ;) ) Oke, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use @dev-null-dweller version if you don't suffer from table ordering. Or you can use a subquery.

```sql
UPDATE stats SET views = views +1 WHERE id = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(id) FROM stats) id)
```

You can profile both solutions and see which one works best for your case.

---

I think the following would be the best solution for you to track the stats, does not require a cronjob.

Create a table with two columns

Table: `stats`

Columns: `stat_date` (DATE) PRIMARY, `views` (INT)

Then run the query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO stats(stat_date, views) VALUES('".date('Y-m-d')."', 1) ".
         'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + 1';
```

*Edit*: I previously suggested a `DATETIME` type for the `stat_date` column, but it's obvious that a `DATETIME` doesn't make sense for you, since you want only a record for a day not a second. Thus, I substituted the `DATETIME` type for `DATE`.

Comment: I was about to write that MySQL wouldn't let you perform an update with subquery on the same table, but then I noticed you've 'hidden' it with another subquery. Clever trick, and it works!

Comment: But will that be more efficient? Also note that I am needing a cronjob anyway, since I'll be counting the number of Androids, etc. on the end of the day. This, to not delay my users with extra %like% statements, or strpos() on their userAgents.

Comment: @SuperSpy I have not profiled a table with a `DATETIME` as `PRIMARY KEY` versus a table with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` of type `INT`. However, logically I believe it would be faster than having to fetch the maximum id and update that record. Then again, this are tiny optimization steps. They fall in the premature optimization boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

You could also sort results by id desc and just edit the first result.

Edit: Too late sorry. :)